# The quotient space of the action of $O(n)$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is homeomorphic to $[0,\infty)$

Tags: general-topology

I have the following problem:

> Let $O(n)$ be the orthogonal group, i.e. $$O(n)=\{M\in GL(n,\mathbb{R}):M^tM=id\}$$ The group has a natural left  action on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Prove that the quotient space of the action of $O(n)$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is homeomorphic to $[0,\infty)$.

I wanted to prove this as follows:

Let us remark that we have the action given as follows $$a:O(n)\times \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n;\,\,\,(M,x)\mapsto Mx$$ But this map can be rewritten with $$a_M:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n;\,\,\,x\mapsto Mx$$Then with this action we can define the orbis as follows:$$O(n)\cdot x=\{a_M(x):x\in \mathbb{R}^n\}$$ on which we have the eq relation $$y \,\,R \,\,x\Leftrightarrow y\in a_M(x)$$ Now we can define the quotient space as follows:$$Q:=\mathbb{R}^n /O(n)=\{[x]:x\in \mathbb{R}^n\}$$. (this part is not really needed to be so precise but I wanted to recap everything)

Now let us use the following function: $$\phi:Q\rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0};\,\,[x]\mapsto ||x||$$. I claim that this function is a homeomorphism. To do so let us check injectivity. Let $[x],[y]\in Q$ s.t. $\phi([x])=\phi([y])\Leftrightarrow ||x||=||y||$. But this is equivalent to say $||Mx||=||My||$ since $M$ is orthogonal. But from here it follows that $[x]=[y]$. For surjectivita let $r\in [0,\infty)$. Then take $R=[(r,0_2,0_3,...,0_n)]$, then $\phi(R)=r$ This shows that $\phi$ is bijective.
Furthermore this function is clearly continuous since it is polynomial in each component. To finish this proof I claim that the inverse of $\phi$ is given by $$\phi^{-1}=\pi:\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} \rightarrow Q;\,\,\,x\mapsto [x]$$Indeed $$\phi^{-1}(\phi([x]))=\phi^{-1}(||x||)=[x]$$ and $$\phi(\phi^{-1}(x))=\phi([x])=||x||=x$$ But since we have endowed $Q$ with the quotient topology we know that $\pi$ is continuous. THus we have shown that it is homeomorphic.

**Remark** I remarked at the end that I don't have to show bijectivity twice, I think it would be enough giving the explicit inverse if this is correct.

Could someone take a look and tell me if this works?

This would be really nice thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is correct. Basically you are saying: $O(n)$ can take a given point to any other point lying in the same sphere centered at the origin. The quotient is thus made of spheres of all possible radii (like layers of an onion), that is why the quotient is essentially (homeomorphic to) the set of all possible radii, $[0,\infty)$

Comment: perfect thanks a lot!